# How to select data by row names

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

Have query like this :

```
declare @tbl TABLE(name varchar(50), [par] varchar(50))

insert into @tbl(name,par)
values('a1','test1'),('a2','test2'),('a3','test3'),('a1','test11'),('a2','test22'),('a3','test33'),('a1','test111'),('a2','test222'),('a3','test333')
```

Result of this query is :

```
 SELECT * FROM @tbl

name    par
a1  test1
a2  test2
a3  test3
a1  test11
a2  test22
a3  test33
a1  test111
a2  test222
a3  test333
```

How to write query for select like this ?

```
a1          a2         a3
test1       test2     test3
test11      test22    test33
test111     test222   test333
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use windowed functions combined with conditional aggregation:

```
;WITH cte AS
(
  SELECT *, rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY name ORDER BY par)
  FROM @tbl
)
SELECT 
  [a1] = MAX(CASE WHEN name = 'a1' THEN par END)
 ,[a2] = MAX(CASE WHEN name = 'a2' THEN par END)
 ,[a3] = MAX(CASE WHEN name = 'a3' THEN par END)
FROM cte
GROUP BY rn;
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/426763)**</kbd>

Output:

```
╔═════════╦═════════╦═════════╗
║   a1    ║   a2    ║   a3    ║
╠═════════╬═════════╬═════════╣
║ test1   ║ test2   ║ test3   ║
║ test11  ║ test22  ║ test33  ║
║ test111 ║ test222 ║ test333 ║
╚═════════╩═════════╩═════════╝
```

---

Alternatively using `PIVOT`:

```
;WITH cte AS
(
  SELECT *, rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY name ORDER BY par)
  FROM @tbl
)
SELECT [a1], [a2],[a3]
FROM cte
PIVOT (MAX(par) FOR name IN ([a1],[a2],[a3])) pvt;
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo2`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/426767)**</kbd>

Note:

If you don't know column names in advance, you could use dynamic pivot.